# Does the probability commute with limit?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Does the probability commute with limit?

For example, is it true that for $(N_t)_t$ random variables which take values in the set of natural numbers,
$$ \mathbb{P}(\underset{t \rightarrow 0}{lim} \hspace{3pt} N_t = 0) = \underset{t \rightarrow 0}{lim} \hspace{3pt} \mathbb{P}(N_t = 0)? $$

Thank you!

Comment: Hmm this might be a stupid question with an obvious answer but how are you defining the left hand side? I can see what the right side means since the $\mathbb{P}$ is always applied to a given random variable which has some specific probability distribution associated with it but I'm not exactly certain how you would unambiguously interpret the left side.

Comment: OP: Did you flag my previous comment? If so, kudos, you succesfully found a way to *avoid* thinking about the problem yourself.

Comment: Me? I didn't flag your previous comment. I didn't read your previous comment.

Comment: because I wasn't here

Comment: OK, someone did, I presume, and a mod took a strange decision.

Comment: Assuming you are using the left hand side to refer to the probability of the limit of the distribution functions for the random variables to equal 0, then have you considered the situation where each $N_t$ is a discrete distribution which has $P(N_t=0)=1/2$ and $P(N_t=1/t)=1/2$?

Comment: In my problem $N_t$ are dicrete random variables. They take values in the set of natural numbers.

Comment: Well in that case look at the example I gave and replace $1/t$ with $\lfloor 1/t\rfloor$.

Comment: Yes. I understand that this is a wrong question. I want to close it :d thank you for explanation

Comment: @rodie: I am sorry to see that you consider your question to be wrong. Perhaps the introductory wording was strange but the question itself made me give an answer. Having accepted my answer, please, let me know if it helped you to get closer to the essence of the issue you raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO in general. Here is an example supporting this negative answer.

Consider the interval $\Omega=[-1,+1)$ and its Borel subsets, and let the probability measure of a subinterval of  $\Omega$ be defined as the half of its length. 
Then, let the random variables $N_t$, with the parameter $t\in (0,1)$ be defined as follows

$$N_t(\omega)=\begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } \omega \in \big[\sin(\frac{1}{t}),\sin(\frac{1}{t})+t \big)\text{ and if }\sin(\frac{1}{t})+t\le1\\
0\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
This function of $\omega$ equals $1$ over an up and down walking and, at the same time,  shrinking interval. So $$\lim_{t\rightarrow0}P(N_t=0)=1.$$
On the other hand there is no $\omega$ for which $$\lim_{t\rightarrow0}N_t(\omega)=0.$$That is$$P(\lim_{t\rightarrow0}N_t=0)=0.$$